# Too many connections error

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am using Magento 1.9.1 with all patches installed on a windows machine and i'm getting this error

```
a:4:{i:0;s:43:"SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections";i:1;s:2730:"#0 ..\path\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 ..\path\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 ..\path\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 ..\path\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 ..\path\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1386): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 ..\path\app\Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 ..\path\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 ..\path\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 ..\path\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Can you try to help me to understand why this happens, and what is the best configuration for Mysql?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you've tried so far to solve your problem.

Comment: At the moment i did not try anything, i thing i have to do some specific configuration in my ini file "my.ini", you think so?

Comment: Well, it sounds like your DB is really busy.

Comment: yes it is so, can you suggest me some configuration or something to change?

Comment: when you say "on a windows machine", do you mean a server or locally on your computer?

Comment: I mean a windows server "2008 R2 Standard", a production PC, i mean that the web site is online

Comment: Check your apache access log for suspicious activity. Maybe a bot is being too aggressive when crawling your site.

Comment: I checked but it seems to be ok maybe I have to change some configuration in mysql

Answer (score 2):

check your MySQL settings in my.cnf file, for beging try to increase the max_connections value. Before start to increasing max_connections check do you have enough resources to do that.

Last I highly recommend you to migrate to Linux based hosting for the Magento system.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to migrate to Linux i will take it for sure into consideration. For now which value do you think is enought for max_connections? now i have max_connections=450 and memory (RAM) is allocated for 2 GB (i have 4 GB)

Comment: mysql -e 'SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections"' -u user -p ----> this will show table check for Threads_connected, to see how many connection you have.
Also check slow log query log http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html  there is a lot of articles that can be useful, google will help you for that.
If you using mysql greater than 5.6 you can connect to it with MySql workbench there is section Performance, that will help you to watch the MySql in real time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, can i use that command in a wondows machine?